# How do I uninstall minefield, now that official Firefox 4.0 is out?

Tags: firefox

Updated from Minefield to official release via `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable`.

Minefield is still installed on my system. How do I get rid of this while retaining the official 4.0 release/PPA?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the package is called "minefield":

```
sudo apt-get remove minefield
```

or if you have purge installed

```
sudo apt-get purge minefield
```